# Capybara, rspec- How to find text anywhere on page

Tags: xpath, capybara

There are multiple ways to find it but I want to do this in a specific manner. Here it is-

To get an element with some text in it, my framework creates an xpath in this manner-

@xpath = "//h1[contains(text(), '[the-text-i-am-searching-for]')]"

Then it executes-

find(:xpath, @xpath).visible?

Now in similar format I want to create an xpath which just looks for a text anywhere in the page and then can be used in find(:xpath,@xpath).visible? to return a true or false.

To give a little more context:
My HTML paragraph looks something like this-

```
<blink><p>some text here <b><u>some bold and underlined text here</u></b> again some text <a   href="www.link">Learn more</a> [the-text-i-am-searching-for]</p></blink>
```

but if I try to find it using find(:xpath, @xpath) where my xpath is
@xpath = "//p[contains(text(), '[the-text-i-am-searching-for]')]"
it fails.

Comment: give proper relevant part of the html,the part you have provided,is not sufficient to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `"//p[contains(text(), '[the-text-i-am-searching-for]')]"` with  `"//p[contains(., '[the-text-i-am-searching-for]')]"`

I don't know your environment but in Python with lxml it works:

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> doc = lxml.etree.HTML("""<blink><p>some text here <b><u>some bold and underlined text here</u></b> again some text <a   href="www.link">Learn more</a> [the-text-i-am-searching-for]</p></blink>""")
>>> doc.xpath('//p[contains(text(), "[the-text-i-am-searching-for]")]')
[]
>>> doc.xpath('//p[contains(., "[the-text-i-am-searching-for]")]')
[<Element p at 0x1c1b9b0>]
>>>
```

The context node `.` will be converted to a string to match the signature `boolean contains(string, string)`  (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions)

```
>>> doc.xpath('string(//p)')
'some text here some bold and underlined text here again some text Learn more [the-text-i-am-searching-for]'
>>>
```

Consider these variations

```
>>> doc.xpath('//p')
[<Element p at 0x1c1b9b0>]

>>> doc.xpath('//p/*')
[<Element b at 0x1e34b90>, <Element a at 0x1e34af0>]

>>> doc.xpath('string(//p)')
'some text here some bold and underlined text here again some text Learn more [the-text-i-am-searching-for]'

>>> doc.xpath('//p/text()')
['some text here ', ' again some text ', ' [the-text-i-am-searching-for]']

>>> doc.xpath('string(//p/text())')
'some text here '

>>> doc.xpath('//p/text()[3]')
[' [the-text-i-am-searching-for]']

>>> doc.xpath('//p/text()[contains(., "[the-text-i-am-searching-for]")]')
[' [the-text-i-am-searching-for]']

>>> doc.xpath('//p[contains(text(), "[the-text-i-am-searching-for]")]')
[]
```

Comment: Thanks, //p/* seems to what I was looking for, I will try it out and will update the results.